# How do I compare the quality of Gifs and PNG using colors. Does calculating the bits per pixel work

Tags: colors, compare, compression, png, gif

Since gif uses 8 bit color dept and png uses 24, I can notice the difference between the two picture.

I want to find the way in which i can compare the colors of two images not by looking but with calculated datas.

What I have done till now is that I calculated the BPP of both gif and png image assuming that would be the best option to compare these two format.

I'm not sure if finding the bpp will give me the absolute color difference or if it is even the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

Although a gif has maximum of 256 colors, it would still have high quality as long as the original "raw" image has less than 256 colors (Imaging a cartoon picture that only used 8 colors, no shading/blending etc). In your question you mentioned you could notice the difference between the two picture, then I assume you are talking about some "raw" image that has more than 256 colors, such as a natural photograph with the sky color gradually changing.

In this case, I think you might check the histogram of the images. For the gif image it will have at most 256 entries in the histogram; for the higher quality png image, it should have a histogram that has a matching shape (peaks and valleys), but more than 256 non-zero entries. If this is true you can almost be certain the png has a higher quality (assuming they are indeed the same picture).

You may even be able to further find out how the gif reduced the number of entries by combining several neighboring entries in the png's histogram into one entry.